# Resize image inside a container?

Tags: jquery, css

To resize a image with the jquery function

`$('div.container').resizable({ aspectRatio:true})`

I put the image in a div like this:

```
.container { width:350px; height:auto; background-color:black}
.container img { width:100%; height:auto}

<div class=container>
    <img .../>
</div>
```

But as you can see here live http://jsfiddle.net/Gz4ts/ 
there is always a little border at the bottom.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*But as you can see here live http://jsfiddle.net/Gz4ts/ there is always a little border at the bottom. How can I fix this?*

Just add:

```
display: block;
```

To the `<img>`, as they're replaced [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) by default

http://jsfiddle.net/Gz4ts/1/

Comment: Omg, where I had only my head... Thx Adrift and greetings from Salzburg in Austria.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `max-width` instead of `width`

```
  .container img { max-width:100%; height:auto}
```